# Azure SQL Server - Can't Access "database.usgovcloudapi.net"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm trying to access an Azure SQL database of mine from SQL Server Management Studio on my local machine and have failed due to requiring 2FA. That's fine, I'll try and sort that.

What concerns me is the server that it's attempting to connect to. What the hell is "database.usgovcloudapi.net"???

[image: SSMS Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is happened when you're using Active Directory Authentication to login your Azure SQL database.

The AD document [Authentication and authorization error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes) show us the error code and message, but doesn't tell us how to solve the problem:

[image]

You need call your AD administrator to re-configure your AD account and try again.

If you still have the error, the document suggest us:

- Have a question or can't find what you're looking for? Create a
  GitHub issue or see [Support and help options for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-support-help-options) to learn
  about other ways you can get help and support.

**Update:**

Congratulations that ataraxia has solved the error:

"Thank you, I got around it by changing the authentication provider to "Active Directory - Universal with MFA Support" on the SSMS login prompt, which then opened a browser window with the regular Microsoft online login and after entering my credentials sent a notification to my mobile, then returned to SSMS and authenticated."

If anyone want details about this, please @ataraxia in the comment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I got around it by changing the (can't remember exact wording) authentication provider as AD with 2FA, which then opened the regular Microsoft online login and sent a notification to my mobile, then returned to SSMS and authenticated. I'm still concerned now that I've seen this, however.

Comment: @ataraxia Congratulations. Since the error has solved now, don't worry. If the error will happen again, I think we still could solved it ! Can I add this to my answer? Then others can reference from you. You can think about accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Or you also can post it and accept it by yourself. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what to do with this as the question was why it's trying to contact this particular server, rather than how to resolve the actual error. There's still no definite answer on this yet, what I'm guessing at the moment is that the server is used for AD authentication only, and has nothing to do with my database other than confirming I have permission to access it. I'm still concerned, and I'd still rather this happens on a UK server seeing as all of my services are set up here.

Comment: Marked this as the answer because yes, the reason the error is appearing and the reason it's trying to contact this database is for AD authentication. I'm not happy with this, so have switched to using a regular SQL Server connection string with SQL user credentials held on the actual server hosting the database that I'm trying to access. Be aware!!

Comment: After a little more research, it seems that this "gov" part of the URI may be misleading. It is the US-based server that is used to authenticate AD users, as I am in the UK it should be using the global server instead, which is https://database.windows.net/. More info can be found here >> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-sql

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Azure Government services, designed for use by US government agencies and their partners.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/government/

Comment: So the US Government has access to my SQL Server?

Comment: No, it's you who are trying to access a US Gov server.  Check your connection string.

Comment: That's the thing, my connection string has no reference to this server at all, it only contains the Azure SQL Server string. I don't want anything to do with the US Government, I'm in the UK, all of my servers and services are in the UK. I don't even want any traffic going to the US due to GDPR and privacy concerns.

Comment: Weird.  Are you trying to connect to your local server using an IP address?

Comment: As per my response to the marked answer, I'm guessing that SSMS is pre-configured to use this server, rather than the global server (which I presume is the one that should be used for me as I'm in the UK)